# What are the instances of usage of four color theorem in the theory of fractional statistics?

Tags: topology, topological-insulators, anyons, quantum-statistics

How important is four-color theorem (Hypothesis) in theory of Fractional Statistics?

Comment: Welcome on Stack-Exchange. Perhaps a bit of motivation and details might help attracting interest form the other users of the platform.

Comment: I am not an expert on Fractional statistics but it applies to only 2 dimensions and so does 4 color theorem. Is there an inherent connection between them ?